# how to resolve uwsgi installation error on mac

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, uwsgi, wsgi

i have the stack trace when i try to pip install uwsgi and i think its related to the mac os or my m1 chip

```
> Collecting uWSGI
  Using cached uwsgi-2.0.20.tar.gz (804 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: uWSGI
  Building wheel for uWSGI (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-iPa0EY
       cwd: /private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/
  Complete output (154 lines):
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-12.0-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  using profile: buildconf/default.ini
  detected include path: ['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
  Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
  detected CPU cores: 10
  configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
  *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
  [thread 0][clang] core/utils.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/protocol.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/socket.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/logging.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/master.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/master_utils.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/emperor.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/notify.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/mule.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/subscription.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/stats.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/sendfile.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/async.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/master_checks.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/fifo.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/offload.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/io.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/static.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/websockets.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/spooler.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/snmp.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/exceptions.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/config.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/setup_utils.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/clock.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/init.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/buffer.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/reader.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/writer.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/alarm.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/cron.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/hooks.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/plugins.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/lock.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/cache.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/daemons.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/errors.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/hash.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/master_events.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/chunked.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/queue.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/event.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/signal.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/strings.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/progress.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/timebomb.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/ini.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/fsmon.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/mount.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/metrics.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/plugins_builder.o
  [thread 2][clang] core/sharedarea.o
  [thread 1][clang] core/rpc.o
  [thread 4][clang] core/gateway.o
  [thread 7][clang] core/loop.o
  [thread 6][clang] core/cookie.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/querystring.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/rb_timers.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/transformations.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/uwsgi.o
  [thread 0][clang] proto/base.o
  [thread 2][clang] proto/uwsgi.o
  [thread 1][clang] proto/http.o
  [thread 4][clang] proto/fastcgi.o
  [thread 7][clang] proto/scgi.o
  [thread 6][clang] proto/puwsgi.o
  [thread 8][clang] core/zlib.o
  [thread 5][clang] core/yaml.o
  [thread 3][clang] core/xmlconf.o
  [thread 9][clang] core/dot_h.o
  [thread 0][clang] core/config_py.o
  *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/python_plugin.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/pyutils.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/python/pyloader.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/python/gil.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/python/profiler.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/python/symimporter.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/python/tracebacker.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/python/raw.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/gevent/gevent.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/gevent/hooks.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/cache/cache.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/nagios/nagios.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/carbon/carbon.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/http/http.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/http/keepalive.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/http/https.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/http/spdy3.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/router_http/router_http.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/logfile/logfile.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/router_static/router_static.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o
  [thread 1][clang] plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o
  [thread 4][clang] plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o
  [thread 7][clang] plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o
  [thread 6][clang] plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o
  [thread 8][clang] plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o
  [thread 5][clang] plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o
  [thread 3][clang] plugins/router_expires/expires.o
  [thread 9][clang] plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o
  [thread 0][clang] plugins/transformation_template/tt.o
  [thread 2][clang] plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o
  *** uWSGI linking ***
  clang -o build/bdist.macosx-12.0-x86_64/wheel/uWSGI-2.0.20.data/scripts/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
  ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.tbd for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  *** error linking uWSGI ***
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uWSGI
  Running setup.py clean for uWSGI
Failed to build uWSGI
Installing collected packages: uWSGI
    Running setup.py install for uWSGI ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-record-eMKev5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/include/site/python2.7/uWSGI
         cwd: /private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/
    Complete output (147 lines):
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'descriptions'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 10
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_OSX_SPINLOCK -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_KQUEUE -DUWSGI_UUID -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.20\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="20" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_EXPAT -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    core/socket.o is up to date
    core/logging.o is up to date
    core/master.o is up to date
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    core/mule.o is up to date
    core/subscription.o is up to date
    core/stats.o is up to date
    core/sendfile.o is up to date
    core/async.o is up to date
    core/master_checks.o is up to date
    core/fifo.o is up to date
    core/offload.o is up to date
    core/io.o is up to date
    core/static.o is up to date
    core/websockets.o is up to date
    core/spooler.o is up to date
    core/snmp.o is up to date
    core/exceptions.o is up to date
    core/config.o is up to date
    core/setup_utils.o is up to date
    core/clock.o is up to date
    core/init.o is up to date
    core/buffer.o is up to date
    core/reader.o is up to date
    core/writer.o is up to date
    core/alarm.o is up to date
    core/cron.o is up to date
    core/hooks.o is up to date
    core/plugins.o is up to date
    core/lock.o is up to date
    core/cache.o is up to date
    core/daemons.o is up to date
    core/errors.o is up to date
    core/hash.o is up to date
    core/master_events.o is up to date
    core/chunked.o is up to date
    core/queue.o is up to date
    core/event.o is up to date
    core/signal.o is up to date
    core/strings.o is up to date
    core/progress.o is up to date
    core/timebomb.o is up to date
    core/ini.o is up to date
    core/fsmon.o is up to date
    core/mount.o is up to date
    core/metrics.o is up to date
    core/plugins_builder.o is up to date
    core/sharedarea.o is up to date
    core/rpc.o is up to date
    core/gateway.o is up to date
    core/loop.o is up to date
    core/cookie.o is up to date
    core/querystring.o is up to date
    core/rb_timers.o is up to date
    core/transformations.o is up to date
    core/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/base.o is up to date
    proto/uwsgi.o is up to date
    proto/http.o is up to date
    proto/fastcgi.o is up to date
    proto/scgi.o is up to date
    proto/puwsgi.o is up to date
    core/zlib.o is up to date
    core/yaml.o is up to date
    core/xmlconf.o is up to date
    [thread 1][clang] core/dot_h.o
    [thread 3][clang] core/config_py.o
    *** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    plugins/python/python_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyutils.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pyloader.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o is up to date
    plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/gil.o is up to date
    plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o is up to date
    plugins/python/profiler.o is up to date
    plugins/python/symimporter.o is up to date
    plugins/python/tracebacker.o is up to date
    plugins/python/raw.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/gevent.o is up to date
    plugins/gevent/hooks.o is up to date
    plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cache/cache.o is up to date
    plugins/nagios/nagios.o is up to date
    plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o is up to date
    plugins/carbon/carbon.o is up to date
    plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o is up to date
    plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o is up to date
    plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/http/http.o is up to date
    plugins/http/keepalive.o is up to date
    plugins/http/https.o is up to date
    plugins/http/spdy3.o is up to date
    plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o is up to date
    plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o is up to date
    plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o is up to date
    plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o is up to date
    plugins/router_http/router_http.o is up to date
    plugins/logfile/logfile.o is up to date
    plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o is up to date
    plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/router_static/router_static.o is up to date
    plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o is up to date
    plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o is up to date
    plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o is up to date
    plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o is up to date
    plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o is up to date
    plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o is up to date
    plugins/router_expires/expires.o is up to date
    plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o is up to date
    plugins/transformation_template/tt.o is up to date
    plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o is up to date
    *** uWSGI linking ***
    clang -o /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/bin/uwsgi  core/utils.o core/protocol.o core/socket.o core/logging.o core/master.o core/master_utils.o core/emperor.o core/notify.o core/mule.o core/subscription.o core/stats.o core/sendfile.o core/async.o core/master_checks.o core/fifo.o core/offload.o core/io.o core/static.o core/websockets.o core/spooler.o core/snmp.o core/exceptions.o core/config.o core/setup_utils.o core/clock.o core/init.o core/buffer.o core/reader.o core/writer.o core/alarm.o core/cron.o core/hooks.o core/plugins.o core/lock.o core/cache.o core/daemons.o core/errors.o core/hash.o core/master_events.o core/chunked.o core/queue.o core/event.o core/signal.o core/strings.o core/progress.o core/timebomb.o core/ini.o core/fsmon.o core/mount.o core/metrics.o core/plugins_builder.o core/sharedarea.o core/rpc.o core/gateway.o core/loop.o core/cookie.o core/querystring.o core/rb_timers.o core/transformations.o core/uwsgi.o proto/base.o proto/uwsgi.o proto/http.o proto/fastcgi.o proto/scgi.o proto/puwsgi.o core/zlib.o core/yaml.o core/xmlconf.o core/dot_h.o core/config_py.o plugins/python/python_plugin.o plugins/python/pyutils.o plugins/python/pyloader.o plugins/python/wsgi_handlers.o plugins/python/wsgi_headers.o plugins/python/wsgi_subhandler.o plugins/python/web3_subhandler.o plugins/python/pump_subhandler.o plugins/python/gil.o plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.o plugins/python/profiler.o plugins/python/symimporter.o plugins/python/tracebacker.o plugins/python/raw.o plugins/gevent/gevent.o plugins/gevent/hooks.o plugins/ping/ping_plugin.o plugins/cache/cache.o plugins/nagios/nagios.o plugins/rrdtool/rrdtool.o plugins/carbon/carbon.o plugins/rpc/rpc_plugin.o plugins/corerouter/cr_common.o plugins/corerouter/cr_map.o plugins/corerouter/corerouter.o plugins/fastrouter/fastrouter.o plugins/http/http.o plugins/http/keepalive.o plugins/http/https.o plugins/http/spdy3.o plugins/signal/signal_plugin.o plugins/syslog/syslog_plugin.o plugins/rsyslog/rsyslog_plugin.o plugins/logsocket/logsocket_plugin.o plugins/router_uwsgi/router_uwsgi.o plugins/router_redirect/router_redirect.o plugins/router_basicauth/router_basicauth.o plugins/zergpool/zergpool.o plugins/redislog/redislog_plugin.o plugins/mongodblog/mongodblog_plugin.o plugins/router_rewrite/router_rewrite.o plugins/router_http/router_http.o plugins/logfile/logfile.o plugins/router_cache/router_cache.o plugins/rawrouter/rawrouter.o plugins/router_static/router_static.o plugins/sslrouter/sslrouter.o plugins/spooler/spooler_plugin.o plugins/cheaper_busyness/cheaper_busyness.o plugins/symcall/symcall_plugin.o plugins/transformation_tofile/tofile.o plugins/transformation_gzip/gzip.o plugins/transformation_chunked/chunked.o plugins/transformation_offload/offload.o plugins/router_memcached/router_memcached.o plugins/router_redis/router_redis.o plugins/router_hash/router_hash.o plugins/router_expires/expires.o plugins/router_metrics/plugin.o plugins/transformation_template/tt.o plugins/stats_pusher_socket/plugin.o -lpthread -lm -lz -lexpat -ldl -framework CoreFoundation /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.a
    ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.tbd for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    *** error linking uWSGI ***
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-install-UZMqSB/uwsgi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/fv/r82y8wns2rsgbxjl0k12zxvc0000gn/T/pip-record-eMKev5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/eliorcohen/placer-django-server/env556/include/site/python2.7/uWSGI Check the logs for full command output.
```

i have an error message when i try to pip install uwsgi on my mac
i dont know if its about the m1 chip or something else it is not clear to me.
do i need to install something?
or do i need to use conda?